# Which equations would allow you to calculate the force exerted on a charged ion moving through a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, magnetic-fields, ions

Due to 'shear' of the electrical double layer when a liquid is forced through a pipe, ions of net charge are mechanically transported in a specific direction. I want to calculate the force that a magnetic field would exert on one of these ions if applied perpendicularly to its direction of motion.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be $\vec{F} = q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}$, like any other charge moving in a magnetic field?  See [the HyperPhysics description](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html), for example.  I don't think the fact that the ion is in a solution would make a difference (though I could be wrong.)

Answer (score -1):

The force on this ion with charge q (positive or negative) is the so called Lorentz force. If you assume the ion velocity v in x-direction, the magnetic field B in y-direction, then the Lorentz force acts in (positive or negative) z-direction and is given by:  F = qv·B